# Redirect after pdf generation PDFTemplateView django

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf, PDFTemplateView to generate a pdf file and I want to render to another view when the generation is finished:

**url:**

```
   url(r'^admin/mymodel/(?P<pdf_id>\d+)/generate/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$',
        my_views.MyModelPdfView.as_view(),
        name="pdf-view"),
    url(r'^admin/mymodel/(?P<pdf_id>\d+)/', my_views.pdf_create_view,
        name="pdf-create"),
```

In a **custom admin view** I have a custom button that generate a pdf:

```
@staff_member_required
def pdf_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    /**** Treating data then calling the pdf view***/
    return redirect('pdf-view', pdf_id=kwargs.get('pdf_id'), 
     pk=commande.id)
```

In my **PDF View:**

```
 class MyModelPdfView(PDFTemplateView):
        model = MyModel
        template_name = 'admin/my_template.html'
        cmd_options = {
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': 0,
            'margin-left': 0,
            'margin-bottom': 0,
            'margin-right': 0,
        }

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(MyModelPdfView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['object'] = MyModel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            return context
```

Comment: use `return redirect('view_name')`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: where in the code you wanna redirect to a view ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I've added more details

Comment: where does the generation of pdf completes ? i.e from which view you wanna redirect to ?

Comment: Well the pdf downloads and then it stucks on the first pdf_create_view I want  to redirect to other view

Comment: try this: `return redirect('admin/mymodel/kwargs.get('event_id')/generate/commande.id/')`

Comment: @Ahtisham where to put it though

Comment: inside `pdf_create_view` at end.

Comment: or try this: `return redirect('MyModelPdfView', {'pdf_id': kwargs.get('pdf_id'), 'pk':'commande.id')`

Comment: Did that helped ?

Comment: Please explain from which view you want to redirect from.